# Table valued parameter problem involving operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-server-2008-r2, table-valued-parameters

I am creating a view which uses a table valued function.

Here is a simple function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TEST(@COD INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN SELECT @COD COD
```

When I execute:

```
SELECT * FROM DBO.TEST(1)
```

it runs perfect, but when I make an operation inside the functions it shows me an error:

```
SELECT * FROM DBO.TEST(1+1)
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '+'.

also when I use parenthesis there is an error:

```
SELECT * FROM DBO.TEST((1+1))
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.

I have another database, when I execute all the examples above it runs perfect. I think it could be a server configuration or database configuration but I don't know what I am looking for.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  As a note, this works fine in SQL Server (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=302d1449eb171f12acd9380485f9b53f).

Comment: Actually the problem occurs in SQL Server, in one database it executes, in the other it shows the error

Comment: Check the database compatibility level of both databases, and try explicitly prefixing the invocation with a schema name (`dbo.TEST`). I seem to recall older versions were more picky about this.

Comment: Thank you. It was the compatibility level in the databases that doesn't work it was 80 and in the other database it was 100. I changed that and now works perfect !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a problem that was fixed at some point in a SQL Server release.

As an alternative, you can use APPLY to correct this problem.

```
SELECT COD
FROM (SELECT 1+1 AS n)x
CROSS APPLY dbo.TEST(x.n);
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, it shows:
```SQL
>Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

Comment: I've added the schema to the function. That should fix the problem.